# Angular NG RX upgrade from 5.X to 6.0 giving compilation error in combindatest

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular6, ngrx

I am using combinelatest in my code and I am passing more than 6 parameters. We just upgraded from 5.x to 6.0 and it's giving compile error. Here is the sample code for it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8znsia?file=index.ts

Error:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<[string, number, number, string,
>   number, number, number], string>' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'OperatorFunction'.   Type '[string, number,
>   number, string, number, number, number]' is not assignable to type
>   'string[]'.
>       Types of property 'pop' are incompatible.
>         Type '() => string | number' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
>           Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>             Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

---

**Edit**

It's not working for operator.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-krkep6?file=index.ts

```
New error: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<string, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<ActionName, {}>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ActionName'
```

Comment: The error is gone if you upgrade to the latest rxjs version. You should also adjust your imports though. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9hgqib

Comment: I can't change the version. I am still seeing error with that version.

Comment: What do you mean you can't change the version? Are you forced to use rxjs 6.0.0 ?

Comment: Yes. That's true.

Answer (score 1):

Your import statements should be adjusted. Did you read the upgrade guide?

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Combinelatest should be imported from 'rxjs' and map should be imported from 'rxjs/operators'

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be gone with rxjs 6.2.1 so upgrade if you can.

Otherwise adding `<any>` to `combineLatest` should get rid of the error.

```
combineLatest<any>(..)
```

See: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3601#issuecomment-384711601

Comment: It's not working as an operator. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-krkep6?file=index.ts . Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @alok_dida you're using rxjs 5.5.8 in the stackblitz but you asked about rxjs 6.0.0 in your question. You don't get the error with rxjs 6.0.0. Additionally `combineLatest` as an operator from `'rxjs/operators'` is deprecated in rxjs 6 and only the static function `combineLatest` from `'rxjs'` should be used. See the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#deprecations)

Comment: @alok_dida if you want to get rid of the typescript error with the `combineLatest` operator in rxjs 5.5 use `combineLatest<any, any>(..)`.

Comment: Yeah that's true. My bad but somehow still it's not working in my application.

Comment: Ahh. I am using it in effect. Is this a reason, I am getting above error?

Answer (score 0):

combineLatest changed from a pipeable operator to a function in rxjs 6

now you import it from the top level

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

and you pass the observable into the function

```
combineLatest(a, b);
```

instead of the old way

```
a.pipe(combineLatest(b));
```